# Is 'unwind' an appropriate term for describing the shrinking phase of a recursive process?

Tags: single-word-requests, programming

Can we say, for instance, that once the base case for a recursive procedure is reached, the recursive process consisting of the evaluation of the procedure 'unwinds'? Here, the term 'unwind' would roughly mean "collects all deferred values until the entry point of the recursive procedure is met."

I understand that 'unwinds' may hint at a 'winding' process occurring beforehand, which happens to be the evaluation of the procedure up to the point of reaching the base case, however, I would not feel comfortable with using 'unevaluates' in order to maintain linguistic symmetry.

Comment: Voting to move to programmers.so, but : 'Unwind' is indeed the word I would use, though it is not specific to a recursive procedure. It refers to the call stack, which can be added to by recursive and non-recursive calls.

Comment: Personally, I would use **rewind**, but in principle they're both suitable. The call stack is central to most implementations of recursion, and this [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) article on the subject uses both words.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Yeah. If you don't need the stack, you could have used a simple loop.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - **rewind** to me implies that it's ready to evaluate again, in the same way, which is not the semantics I'm trying to name.

Comment: I agree with the commenters: unwind is the standard terminology, and it refers to the stack. Often "unwind the stack" is in fact the description. If you are using a non recursive method, contrary to the question, unwind would be less appropriate, and would be used more as an analog to the recursive.

Comment: @JeffSahol, could you comment on the intended meaning of the 'programming' tag and how this question is off-topic? Most related questions to this one with the 'programming' tag seem to fall into the same category and be of very similar nature, yet have not been closed nor put on hold.

Comment: @AlexisPetrounias, I didn't add the programming tag, so I can't comment on the general question about that. I flagged this as off-topic because it's really a programming question, a question about how to describe what goes on in the processing of a recursive function, and not so much a question about language per se. It's a good question, in my opinion, just not as well suited for english.se as for programmers.se. BTW, how about coining "decurse" as the verb for what happens when a function stops recursing and goes the opposite direction?

Comment: @JeffSahol, if I understand correctly, you also consider most if not all of the related questions to this one as off topic? Perhaps over the years such questions have become relevant to this se? It seems awkward that the tag programming is used extensively to characterize the now many questions of this very nature, yet this question in particular remains closed. In the interest of consistency with the rest of this se, could you elaborate on why this question should remain closed while most programming-tagged questions of a similar nature remain open?

Comment: @JeffSahol, "decurse" is an interesting idea, however there is the possibility of confusion with the the process of elimination of a recursive process; i.e. "decurse" could be understood as the removal of recursive definitions or procedures from a program, either by removing them altogether or by transforming them into iterative equivalents. I would suspect the same goes for "uncurse".

Comment: @AlexisPetrounias, I don't really understand the need for a "programming" tag at all. However, looking a the first few positively voted examples today, I see "Is there a way to measure how 'emotive' a verb is?" and "Word for light after it has passed through a window / glass". Both of those can be answered without understanding programming. And the answers will not hinge on a technical detail such as what happens to the call stack during a recursive vs non-recursive call.